Merge digits into numbers within a list
I have a generated list:
{{3}, {2}, {3, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {5}, {5, 3}, {5, 2, 3}, {5, 9}, {3, 5, 9}, {5, 9, 3}, {9, 5, 3}}
I want to have as output:
3, 2, 31, 13, 23,....953, etc
I know I have to use FromDigits but how do I apply it to the set above...
Thanks!

You need to Map the FromDigits on your list:
FromDigits /@ {{3}, {2}, {3, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {5}, {5, 3}, {5, 2, 
   3}, {5, 9}, {3, 5, 9}, {5, 9, 3}, {9, 5, 3}}


+1 Greetings, mate, I hope you are well!

@E.Chan-López All is fine more or less, just a series of too hectic months at work. Hopefully I will be fully back before Christmas. Hope all is well with you mate!

Hi, mate! I want to nominate you as a moderator, but I don't know if it's possible.

@E.Chan-López thanks for this, but I don't know if it's possible. Besides, I am starting a new job in one month and I am not sure about the new volume of responsibilities. I appreciate the thought :-)

Hi @bmf  : The solution does not work if numbers are more than 1 digit?  Ex:  FromDigits /@ {{1, 3}, {1, 7}, {1, 13}, {345, 1}, {3, 45}}   -->  {13, 17, 23, 3451, 75}   I want this as output:  13,17,113,3451,345

@Steve237 hey, thanks for letting me know. So, I think you need to break up the big numbers and then ArrayReshape the list. For example check the command IntegerDigits[{345, 1}]. From that you just have to combine /@ or @ or @@ or @@@ appropriately. I will try to give it a go over the next few days, however, I am relocating and changing continents, so I cannot make a promise that I will find sufficient time to revisit.

Sure thanks @bmf -- However the solution has to work for an unknown number length! Not just a length of 2 or 3...what if it is a 7 or 10 digit number...

For something different:
d[u_] := 10^Range[Length[u] - 1, 0, -1] . u

So,
a = {{3}, {2}, {3, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {5}, {5, 3}, {5, 2, 3}, {5, 
    9}, {3, 5, 9}, {5, 9, 3}, {9, 5, 3}};
d /@ a

->
{3, 2, 31, 13, 23, 5, 53, 523, 59, 359, 593, 953}


Hi @ubpdqn : see above comment to bmf which I just added....any solutions for that? Thx
